# Win7 running new ImageResizer 3.1

Tags: windows-7, bricelambson-image-resizer

I've downloaded updated Image Resizer 3.1, uninstalled previous version, and installed the new one.
Now it opens when righ-clicking on an image, but I get errors when trying to resize images (and images are not resized).
The error is something like this (I am translating from Spanish to English):

```
Images cannot be resized
7432
Could not find file 'C:\Windows\7432'
p
Could not find file 'C:\p'
```

The number 7432 changes everytime I try to resize. 
Help appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, are `7432` and `p` the names of images, or in any way related to, or part of, something you entered?  Have you rebooted? Are any other actions messed up?  Have you tried reloading the old version to see whether it has the same problem?  Have you tried downloaded the current version from another source (especially the publisher if you got it from a general software download site)?  This is obviously not normal behavior, so diagnosing it will take a lot more details.

Comment: No, neither the numbers (that changed at every trial) nor "p" were anything relevant I was aware of. I uninstalled 3.1 and installed 3.0 and worked fine. I contacted the designer and had an answer (see my new reply): the new version 3.1 required a windows restart. After rebooting windows, no more errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug reported [here](https://github.com/bricelam/ImageResizer/issues/70):

> This is caused by the old (3.0) shell extension calling the new (3.1) app.

The solution was quite easy... restart windows.
(although restarting was not necessary on previous versions)

Comment: Response to PS: You shouldn't edit the question itself to include the solution, instead, you write an answer and mark it as accepted. Answering to your own question is [encouraged on all SE sites](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). Also, welcome to Superuser!

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  You can accept your own answer (click the checkmark next to it), but you have to wait 2 days from posting the question to do that (the wait applies only to your own answer).

Comment: Also, don't add "Solved" to your question title. When it passes 2 days you accept your answer and it's automatically understood by others as solved.

Comment: Nice research.  I beefed up the answer a little with relevant info from your link.  Ordinarily, this would have been unsolvable based on the information in the question, but it turned out to be the signature of a known bug.  I didn't see your solution on the GitHub page, so consider sharing it there with the developer.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the tips :). Tomorrow I'll "accept" the answer as suggested.